# Need help understanding Foreign Key Conflict in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I know this seems trivial, and there are a ton of questions in regards to it...

I have two tables:

```
Product (ProductID PK 1,1)
Product_Image (ProductID, ImageFile)
```

In SSMS Design mode, I created a Foreign Key relationship.

```
Foreign Key Base Table: Product_Image
Foreign Key Columns: ProductID
Primary/Unique Key Base Table: Product
Primary/Unique Key Column: ProductID
```

In my application, the insert works fine, but when editing, I get the wonderful error:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Product_Image_Product".
The conflict occurred in database "testdb", table "dbo.Product", column 'ProductID'.
```

What's happening is when my application triggers the update stored procedure, it deletes all images from the Product_Image table based on the ProductID, and then adds them back in depending on what images the user selects.

So first, it updates the main table:

```
UPDATE Product SET.... etc.
```

Then it deletes all images associated with that product:

```
DELETE FROM Product_Image WHERE ProductID = @ProductID
```

Then, it adds them back in based on the delimited string... ('image1.jpg|image2.jpg|image3.jpg')

```
WHILE LEN(@Images) > 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Product_Image ( ProductID, ImageFile ) VALUES ( @ProductID, LEFT(@Images, CHARINDEX('|', @Images+'|') -1) )
        SET @Images = STUFF(@Images, 1, CHARINDEX('|', @Images+'|'), '')
END
```

This does not work when I have the FK setup on the tables... However, I'm able to open a new query window in SSMS and do a delete from the Product_Image table and an insert right back into it with an existing productID from the Product table.

Maybe I'm missing something silly. I hope so.

Thank you!

======= EDIT ========

Adding more clarity of steps...

After creating the two tables and inserting data into the product table.

I right click over the Product_Image table, and select Design. I right click over the design area and select "Relationships". I click "Add" and then expand tables and columns, and click the little "..." button to use the interface to do it. For the primary key table, I find the "Product" table and select ProductID for the Column. The foreign key table I select ProductID from the Product_Image table... then I saved the table.

So when a product is edited through the application, it uses a stored procedure to update the data.

When it gets to the images, it attempts to delete all images from Product_Image table that are associated with the ProductID. Then it inserts them, as seen above... If I open a query window in SSMS and type:

```
DELETE FROM Product_Image WHERE ProductID = 10
INSERT INTO Product_Image ( ProductID, ImageFile ) VALUES ( 10, 'test.jpg' )
```

It works...

Comment: "When editing"...Is this implying that you're attempting to insert a new row by hand into Product_Image? That you're attempting to update a row? A bit more specificity, if you can't provide the actual SQL statements.

Comment: Will add more details... one moment and thank you!

Comment: I assume he's gone into SSMS, right clicked a table and selected edit top 200 rows

Comment: @JaazCole I just realized what you meant by your comment/question. "When Editing" I'm referring to the web app that interacts with the data. I'm not "editing top 200 rows."

Comment: @JaazCole I edited my question to add more clarity to the steps on creating the FK.

Comment: Does your app update/deletes through a DB procedure or a open query framed by itself?

Comment: @Anand It simply executes a SQL Stored Procedure.

Comment: Ok, what are the chances that SSMS could have bugged out on me yesterday? I gave up trying to solve the problem last night, and today... the error does not occur. I didn't change a thing. Perhaps I'm losing it.